# How to access element inside DataGrid header from code-behind in WPF

Tags: wpf, datagrid, contentcontrol

I'm currently implementing filter capabilities on a `DataGrid`. I redefined the `DataGridColumnHeader` as follows (the `ToggleButton` gives access to a `Popup` which I don't detail and simplify the code for clarity).

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <ContentControl Content="{Binding}" />
                    <ToggleButton Name="FilterToggleButton" Grid.Column="1" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

All columns are specified as follow :

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Example">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Example}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

I would like to access the `ToggleButton` from code-behing corresponding to the column with a given `Header` value. I'm able to identify the column where `dataGrid` is the name of the `DataGrid`. I believe there is no direct link between `column` and it's header `ContentTemplate` as `column.HeaderTemplate` is `null`. How do I get the `FilterToggleButton` from the `column`?

```
foreach (var column in dataGrid.Columns)
{
    var header = column.Header; // String with cast required, but I expected it to be the ContentTemplate.
    
    if (header == lookupHeader)
    {
        // How do I get the FilterToggleButton from the column?
    }
}
```

I also tried to first list all toggle buttons `var tgls = UIHelpers.FindChildren<ToggleButton>(dataGrid);` and then used the #well-know# UI `FindParent()`, `FindChildren()` to get the corresponding header without success.

Comment: May I ask why you need to get the button? This is not common. Maybe there is a better solution. Just as a note, there is the DataGridTextColumn of you want to display the cell value as simple text. This would simplify your XAML.

Comment: I would like to change the appearance of the toggle button if the column is filtered from external "Quick filters" (not part of the DataGrid). For the time being, I'm able to act on the displaid rows and restore the appearance of all the filter toggle buttons (via event aggregator).

Comment: This can be accomplished via a Style and style triggers.

Comment: Sure, but for the time being, I don't have a specific view model to handle all the filter popups and so on.

Comment: You don't handle styles in the view model. You define a Style in XAML as usual that contains triggers that trigger on certain conditions (you didn't tell) to change the appearance in a certain way (you didn't tell).

Comment: The problem with your question is that you seem to believe that your strategy is correct in general but you struggle to implement it. That's why you reduced the provided information to a bare minimum in context to finding that ToggleButton. Obviously, your strategy is not the best but your question lacks the general context that is required to make any suggestions. I guess the fact that your strategy is wrong doesn't help much. Whenever you find yourself digging for elements deep down the element tree you are likely pursuing a wrong solution.

Comment: At least it gives some results for the time being. By the way, how do you bind elements which are in 2 differents user controls? I have a user control for the DataGrid with several hundred code-behind lines to manage the Popup content (basically, filters like Excel) and the Quick filters in another user-control. It is why I use an event aggregator to communicate between the Quick filters and the DataGrid. (I intended to implement such Excel-like filters for a couple of years for my own WPF project but avoided by moving to ASP.Net and now have to do it for my job... kind of challenge).

Comment: Filters should be applied by the type that owns the data source (e.g., source collections). You have some options to trigger filtering 1) Use routed commands that the popup uses to trigger the filter operations. Then a parent element (the owner of the data source) handles the routed command by executing the filter operation. 2 ) Use routed events that the owner of the Popup (e.g. your custom control) raises. Then a parent element (the owner of the data source) handles the routed command by executing the filter operation. This is the basic structure or infrastructure.

Comment: Now to address your filter scenarios (quick filter vs normal filter), you can introduce dedicated routed commands, for example a `QuickFilterNamesCommand` (solution #1) or routed events, for example `QuickFilterNamesRequested` (solution #2). The handler of the commands/events can now invoke the appropriate action based on the specific request. I would consider this a clean and simple solution.  Clean in design and simple in terms of implementation and maintenance.

Comment: The idea is to not scatter responsibilities (filtering a collection) across multiple places/controls/classes. That's a general principle. There should be only a single type that needs to be modified in order to modify the filtering. Both your controls must only trigger the filter operation, but not execute them themselves. This eliminates a lot of smelly code and complexity like the introduction of an event aggregator etc.

Comment: Thanks for your explanations. In fact, I already added routed commands `UpdateFilterCommand` and `ApplyFilterCommand` (at least I think so) in the code-behind to avoid `DataContext` cast to the view model, but it can probably be improved from the root. I will continue to learn about WPF and probably restructure later on. Anyway, I can't believe all the work required to just add `DataGrid` filter capabilities (or I probably missed something from the begining... and I can't rely on 3rd party paid libraries).

Comment: It really depends on what you are trying to achieve. Filtering a DataGrid is actually pretty simple and straight forward. To filter the data you usually use the collection view of the collection.

Answer (score -1):

Alright, I just came up with an idea which seems to work event though there are probably way cleaner codes! Just wondering why there is one toggle button more that the column headers (probably for the default row number column which I don't show?)

```
var index = 0;

foreach (var column in dataGrid.Columns)
{
    var header = column.Header;

    if (header == lookupHeader)
    {
        var tgls = UIHelpers.FindChildren<ToggleButton>(dataGrid);

        var tgl = tgls[index + 1]; // TODO: Investigate why there is one toggle button more.

        // ...
    }

    index++;
}
```